# Checkbox loose it status on buttonclick event

Tags: asp.net

I have created one web page.In that I want like this,when user enter more than 0 character in textbox,checkbox should get selected.In buttonclick event if checkbox is checked,print something.
When user enter more than 0 character,checkbox get checked.But When user click on button,that time it show checkbox.checked = false.Why this so?

In aspx page

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function displaycharcount()
    {
      if(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value.length   > 0)
      document.getElementById('CheckBox1').checked = true;
    }
    </script>

//
//textbox
//checkbox
// button
```

// In cs file

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", " return displaycharcount()");
    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            Response.Write("Printing .......");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The button is runat=server?

Comment: yes, button has runat = server

Comment: So it do a postback when it pressed and the page is drowing again. And the checkbox checked = false.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you access the value of `CheckBox1.Checked` from c# serverside code, it fetches the value from viewstate. When you update the CheckBox's checked property from javascript client side code, it cann't update that viewstate. That's why you are getting `checkbox.checked = false` in button clicked event.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are setting checkbox attribute in javascript that is client side code and that calling a button click which is a server side code.

I would suggest you to use a hidden field and set its value where you are cheking/uncheking check box.

In server side on button click check the value of this hidden field instead of check box and proceed.

I am not posting code, i am letting you to try this approach first and if found any difficulty than we may help you